# Hangouts Error on Android Phone: Cannot connect to the server

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, google-hangouts, att

I'm getting a "cannot connect to the server" error when I try to use Hangouts on my phone. Every other Google app works. SMS works but not Hangouts messages. All my other devices work with Hangouts messages.

Comment: Is the time, date, and time zone correct for its location? Maybe some failed connection is occuring because of inaccurate authentication.

Comment: Yes, all those are correct, wbpgacz.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this issue is due to the restricted background data setting.

Navigate to Settings -> Data Usage

Find the following apps and make sure "Restrict Background Data" is switched off:

- Hangouts app
- Google Services
- Google Play Store

Answer (score -2):

Go to Settings > Apps > swipe right to "All" > click the menu button of 3 vertical dots > click on "Reset app preferences".

Comment: NOOO..!!
If you do that you are going to **RESET ALL** APP PREFERENCES!!
In Settings > Apps > find Hangouts app and delete data or unistal and install again